# Issue with Api call, not returning any response in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const routerid = (itemId) =>
  axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=" + itemId);
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, key) in user" :key="key">
      {{ item.price }} <br />
      {{ item.description }} <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { routerid } from "./routerid";
export default {
  name: "User",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.$route.params.id)
      routerid(this.$route.params.id).then((r) => {
        let obj = r.data;
        this.lists = [{ ...obj }];
      });
  },
  computed: {
    user: function () {
      return this.lists.filter((item) => {
        return item.id === this.$route.params.id;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

How to make axios url call with query params like this..**https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=1** Where you can see in the url i have ...like ?limit=id.... So i am little bit confused about it..How to call

Did i correctly call the api or anything missing in the code logic. As of now, In my  output, I cant see any response from the api.

Code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-ives-h19zm7?file=/src/components/routerid.js

Comment: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-query-params

Comment: you're using the `itemId` as the limit of records being returned? that means if you pass in 1, you get first record, 2 you get the first two records, 3, the first three records etc ... it seems odd to use a property called `id` to actually refer to the number of records you want .... anyway, what number are you passing to that function - i.e. what is `this.$route.params.id`

Comment: @Bravo numbers like 1,2,3,4...... For example from the router-link if i click on id:-4(then in url, it passes like this)

https://h19zm7.csb.app/#/4?id=4

Comment: @Bravo Can changes in the code, solves this issue. or alternatives Please

Comment: right, so, when you click in id 4, you'll get 4 results, id 3, you get 3 ... etc, I think you have confused what `limit` is ... did you want JUST id 4, or JUST id 3 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to fetch a product by its ID?
Then it rather would be:

```
export const routerid = async (itemId) =>
  await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/" + itemId);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-nightingale-ixz8tr

Comment: Checked the code sandbox,  After clicking on the router-link getting. 

Error as Request failed with status code 404

Comment: yea i missed a `/` after products in the url check again pls

Comment: :) It's working. But it's taking approximately **13seconds to 15 seconds** of time  to get the response. Is it something like common ??

Comment: mine isn't taking that long. it should not be common.

Comment: Thanks once again... :)